# Tracking .com & .com.mx domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to set up Google Analytics to track two language versions of the same site: example.com and example.com.mx. Right now, we have it setup under two different profiles, each with the standard (different numbers) tracking code. That method doesn't seem to track the sites correctly.

My question: is this the correct implementation for the example.com, example.com.mx scenario or does it need to be setup as suggested be Google in the link below?

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503

Thanks in advance for any input...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether you have many visitors visiting both sites - if you use different webproperty IDs (UA-XXXXXXX-Y and UA-XXXXXXX-Z), a user visiting both will be counted as 2 unique visitors, 2 visits, so your unique Visitor count will be inflated.

That is because GA uses first party cookies only for identifying unique visitors, so the cookie is unique to the domain.

If you don't care about Unique Visitor duplication, you can use 2 different webproperty ids, and even just one and separate the sites with profile-level filters.

If you do want to see both sites as only one entity, you should use _setDomainName.

Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html for implementation advice.